# Tumblr quick like button not working

Tags: javascript, tumblr

**EDIT, April 2013:** Old code no longer nedeed. Use Tumblr's new shortcodes for 'like' and 'reblog' buttons instead!

http://developers.tumblr.com/post/49193689915/attn-fantastic-theme-developers-tumblr-users-can

**Old code:**

I'm using @ThinkingStiff's code (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9048446/351320).

Here's the live example: http://themelab01.tumblr.com/

My html code:

```
    {block:Posts}
        {block:Text}
            <li id="{PostID}" class="post text">
                {block:Title}
                    <h3><a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a></h3>
                {/block:Title}

                {Body}
            </li>
            <a href="{ReblogURL}" class="reblog">reblog</a>
            <a href="#" class="like">like</a>
        {/block:Text}
```

css

```
#like-it {
    display: none;
}
.liked, .like:hover {

    color: red !important;
}
```

js

```
$(document).on('click', '.like', function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var command = $(this).hasClass('liked') ? 'unlike' : 'like',
        post = $(this).closest('.post'),
        oauth = post.find('.reblog').attr('href').slice(-8),
        id = post.attr('id'),
        likeUrl = 'http://www.tumblr.com/' + command + '/' + oauth + '?id=' + id;

    $('#like-it').attr('src', likeUrl);
    $(this).toggleClass('liked');

});
```

and the empty iframe is at the bottom of the page. However this isn't working. When I click on 'like' the number of liked post in my dashboard increases (where it says "Liked n. posts) but the post does not appear in the Likes page and the text should stay red but it doesn't. What am I missing?

Comment: I posted updated code below. In your example above you have `{PostID}` inside of a `{block:Text}`. This means it would not be visible on other post types, like pictures. Also, I don't see the `like-it` `<iframe>` so that could be the issue as well. The easiest solution is to use my new code though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated my code recently to make it a cut and paste endeavor. This eliminates the need for jQuery and the post ID, two areas people always have trouble with.

The tutorial is here: http://like-button.tumblr.com

Cut and paste the following code block into your theme immediately before `</head>`. This will give you a like button on each post that looks like the default Tumblr grey heart. It will turn red when you hover over it and when you click it. If you click it again, it will turn grey again and delete the Like.

```html
<style>
.my-like {
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABMAAAARCAYAAAA/mJfHAAABH0lEQVQ4y62T30vCUBiGv/9YuhBLkCA08FdogRFFYFEUhhZNCCQoSESiIOii68pl5qV6s8Eb7+SMHXNs6S7ejZ3zvA+ccT4BICofvS88dJ7w8vqG8WQC754K17lPjrx3z3l8D4YoVaqIrWbcJNbzaHefNZjfXPdy5b0jsO/IRqMxUpmSBnhz2bx1QL79GPbpEePmzhdSyW8fBDL0SK68HwiGCT2S3NiKREaPzP7QRRNPZSHpwm4kMnqkYbQikdEjZv8HK2ubS4nY75mD6WU8qzeXkrHvToBlWSjuHC4kYo99V8bwBnM0/iMiz542myq2bSPskcmR/zPos7lvP8Lv/nGd+/N6c2Xq2KcXhiY6qV1rxwotU3n/NHF8fgW+g9hfsHJlJUYljcgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) !important;
    height:17px;
    width:19px;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.my-liked, .my-like:hover {
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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) !important;
    height:17px;
    width:19px;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
</style>
<script>
window.onload = function () {
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', '<iframe id="my-like-frame" style="display:none;"></iframe>' );
document.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {
    var myLikeLink = event.target;
    if( myLikeLink.className.indexOf( 'my-like' ) > -1 ) {
        var myLikeFrame = document.getElementById( 'my-like-frame' ),
            liked = ( myLikeLink.className == 'my-liked' ),
            command = liked ? 'unlike' : 'like',
            reblog = myLikeLink.getAttribute( 'data-reblog' ),
            postId = myLikeLink.getAttribute( 'data-id' ),
            oauth = reblog.slice( -8 ),
            likeUrl = 'http://www.tumblr.com/' + command + '/' + oauth + '?id=' + postId;
        myLikeFrame.src = likeUrl;
        liked ? myLikeLink.className = 'my-like'
            : myLikeLink.className = 'my-liked';
    };
}, false );
};
</script>
```

Then cut and paste the following button code into your theme where you want your like button to be (this must be inside your `{block:Posts}` block).

Code:

```html
<div class="my-like" data-reblog="{ReblogURL}" data-id="{PostID}"></div>
```

Comment: Oh great. Thanks! I should've re-checked the main source first. Gonna try it now :D Btw, is there a way to tweak this so that the js can be placed the bottom of the page instead? I'm using html5 Boilerplate and it would be great to have all the code just in one place. http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/plugins.js-and-script.js/#scriptjs

Comment: @Barbara Yes, it can be at the bottom of the page. I might change my tutorial since more people put code at the bottom.

Comment: That would be awesome. Thanks!